# Put an image on a photo iOS/Android

Tags: android, ios, photo, editing

I'm trying to understand if I can edit a pic by using another image to put on the photo just taken.
I will develop an app for iOS and Android that implements function to add image to a photo takes by the camera and I wanted to ask you if there's a way to do this feature.
For example: I take a photo and before I save it, I will put over this photo a PNG file, it's possible in iOS and Android?
Thank you

Comment: Yeah that will be possible, I don't know the code but you will be able to do that.

Comment: I haven't done that but I have taken a photo and paint over there, so It's possible. At least what I did it was work with the context and apply the changes you have made to your image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can definietly do that. I have similar functionality in my app - after taking a photo, character image is placed on top of it.

Sample code for iOS:

```
- (UIImage *)makeImageUsingPhoto:(UIImage *)photo andCharacter:(UIImage *)character atPosition:(CGPoint)position
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions( photo.size, FALSE, 1.0 );

    [photo drawInRect:CGRectMake( 0, 0, photo.size.width, photo.size.height )];
    [character drawInRect:CGRectMake( position.x, position.y, character.size.width, character.size.height * ratio)];

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Comment: Thank you I think that this snippet will be very useful for my code :)